# How come I can't get this PJAX example working?

Tags: d3.js

This page demonstrates how to use PJAX in d3 to load external html files:
https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1367999

I've made an exact copy of this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1531353/Misc/Docudocker/trialpjax/trial.html

However, my version is not working. I am getting a DOM error when I click on a link (instead of having the html get loaded onto the page). I have tried to use Chrome console to find out what exactly is causing the DOM error to no avail. Is there something I forgot to copy over?

Comment: It seems you have it working now?

Comment: Yes! Thank you friend! Sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: No problem, I thought you might have solved it by yourself! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load `pjax("ul li a", "#main");` the `content` variable is set to "#main"

So, in this function:

```
function load(href) {
    d3.html(href, function(fragment) {
      var target = d3.select(content).node();
      target.parentNode.replaceChild(d3.select(fragment).select(content).node(), target);
      pjax(links, content); // reapply
    });
  }
```

In the line:

```
target.parentNode.replaceChild(d3.select(fragment).select(content).node(), target);
```

It's looking for the contents of `#main`, within the document fragment which was loaded.

However, in your case, there is no `#main` so it gets set to null. When you try to call replaceChild with null, you get the error you're experiencing.

To fix it, set your other pages up as he has done, with a `#main` in each.